# How will AngularJS run in the presence of real-time polymorphism

Tags: javascript, security, angularjs

The Financial Times just reported in the article "Google-backed venture uses shape-shifting code to defeat hackers" that real-time polymorphism may be the next leap in cyber security. [Shape Security](http://www.shapesecurity.com) has attracted investors from Google Ventures, Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter and DropBox.

Shape Security's Technology page shows that cleartext html's like this:

```
<form action="login_form.php">
  <input id="username" name="username"/>
  <input id="password" name="password"/>
  <input id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"/>
  <input id="login" name="login"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

will be dynamically transformed such that binding names are changed on each page request, for instance to:

```
<form action="d94M2eQgBK">
  <input id="v6DbNQEs4z" name="dtTtA6tsmi"/>
  <input id="b5KbBSjCT6" name="rWttCLcv3f"/>
  <input id="zQNA3ZBgKz" name="R2bHEe3taV"/>
  <input id="rvnFbpxKwN" name="HNnQwnUbtm"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

In AngularJS we'd likely use the directive `ng-model` to have angular bind fields at the html level to javascript variables in a controller. Real-time polymorphism will have to change the variable name in the controller as well. At some point as one goes deeper these changes have to stabilize so that controller variables can be passed back to services, etc.

It seems that a directive like `ng-polymorph-model` could wrap the expected polymorphism. However, any degree of stability in the DOM or js code served to the client is a vector for future attack.

I'm curious how the AngularJS experts will approach real-time polymorphism.

Comment: This would affect all kind of frameworks not only angular.js. What about jQuery and even css selectors?

Comment: This seems like a red herring. We've been through obfuscation before. Passwords are more likely to be hacked through social engineering or by inspecting the payload than by understanding what the label for a field is.

Comment: What is the red herring here? I am very interested in Shape Security's technology and am trying to understand the impact on the DOM / js frameworks out there, in particular AngularJS since I use this. I'd appreciate constructive contributions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest this will not effect any framework but it depends on how you write your code.

Here is an example of how to avoid issues.

You will need to ensure you store string representations of id's and attributes within an object and name them accordingly.

instead of:

```
var username = document.getElementById('username');
```

you will do this:

var username = document.getElementById(ids.username);

Now to achieve this you need to create an object and create variables which you will point to for reference:

```
var ids = {
            submit : "submit",
            username : "username",
            password : "password",
            email : "email"
        }
```

So when you encrypt the id's on your elements then you need to replace the string in the 'ids' objects. Below is an example of an encrypting

```
 function encrypt() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id]");
            for (var a = 0; a < elems.length; a++) {
                var elem = elems[a];
                if (ids[elem.id])
                {
                    var name =elem.id;
                    var g  = guid();
                    elem.id =g;
                    ids[name] =g;
                }
            }
            console.log(ids);
        }
 function s4() {
            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
        };

        function guid() {
            return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        }
```

What this is doing is grabbing all elements with id attributes and looping through them, changing id attributes and updating the 'ids' object with the correct reference name.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry for my delay in studying your post. Thank you for your answer. This is a nice piece of indirection. It seems to me that if this code is placed on the client browser then the indirection can be reversed. Today likely few will do this, spiders will just return garbage. I suppose, though, keeping the js indirection code local is the purpose for the 1U box Shape Security is selling. thx again.